# How can i loop my timer?

Tags: javascript, loops, timer, countdown

I have been trying for half a day to loop this countdown function. I do not want to create different countdown. How do I go about looping it? Please take note that this is a countdown timer with interval of 1 second. My site is here http://jian.comoj.com/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    setInterval('countdown()',1000);

    function countdown(){

        var now = new Date();

        var unix_now= now.getTime()/1000;

        unix_now= Math.floor(unix_now);


        var sec = <?php echo $end_time[0]; ?> - unix_now;


        if(sec<=0){
            clearInterval(stop);

        }



        var min = Math.floor(sec / 60);
        var hour = Math.floor(min / 60);

        hour %= 24;
        min %= 60;
        sec %= 60;

        document.getElementById(0).innerHTML= hour+":"+min+":"+sec;


    }

    setInterval('countdown1()',1000);

    function countdown1(){

        var now = new Date();

        var unix_now= now.getTime()/1000;

        unix_now= Math.floor(unix_now);


        var sec = <?php echo $end_time[1]; ?> - unix_now;


        if(sec<=0){
            clearInterval(stop);

        }



        var min = Math.floor(sec / 60);
        var hour = Math.floor(min / 60);

        hour %= 24;
        min %= 60;
        sec %= 60;

        document.getElementById(1).innerHTML= hour+":"+min+":"+sec;


    }

    setInterval('countdown2()',1000);

    function countdown2(){

        var now = new Date();

        var unix_now= now.getTime()/1000;

        unix_now= Math.floor(unix_now);


        var sec = <?php echo $end_time[2]; ?> - unix_now;


        if(sec<=0){
            clearInterval(stop);

        }



        var min = Math.floor(sec / 60);
        var hour = Math.floor(min / 60);

        hour %= 24;
        min %= 60;
        sec %= 60;

        document.getElementById(2).innerHTML= hour+":"+min+":"+sec;


    }

</script>
```

Comment: the line `setInterval('countdown()',1000);` is not ideal. It will cause the `eval()` to be run on the string `'coutndown()'` which is sub-optimal. Instead just pass the funstion name to `setInterval()` like `setInterval(countdown,1000);` but remember to remove the brackets otherwise it will execute the function there and then and replace it with the value returned from the function (if there is one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `setInterval` inside the countdown functions too. Something like recursive calling.